# Clarification regarding this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}) and this.shadowRoot

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, native-web-component

### Regarding native `WebComponents`:

In the `constructor()` method at the start of the `class` it's conventional to attach a shadow DOM tree to the `Custom Element` and return a reference to its `ShadowRoot`:

```
class myCustomElement extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();
    const shadowroot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
  }

 [... REST OF CODE HERE...]

}
```

The name of the reference can, of course, be *anything*.

I have seen:

- `var shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});` (see: [`Element.attachShadow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attachShadow))
- `this.root = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});`

by we could just as easily use:

- `const myShadowRootzzz = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});`

---

However, there *already* exists [`Element.shadowRoot`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/shadowRoot) which ***is*** the `ShadowRoot` reference.

So why is the syntax

```
const shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
```

so commonly used in examples, when simply stating:

```
this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});
```

would be sufficient, since... any time the `ShadowRoot` needs to be referenced, that reference is, literally:

```
this.shadowRoot
```

Why would the WebComponent's `ShadowRoot` need *another* arbitrary reference beyond `this.shadowRoot` ?

Am I missing something important... or can I safely omit such additional references in my own `WebComponents`?

Comment: It occurred to me that a reference like `const shadowroot1 = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});` _would make sense_ if a single `CustomElement` could be given _multiple_ `ShadowRoots`. It seems at one point (long ago) this _was_ possible, albeit [the idea of multiple `ShadowRoots` was ditched in 2015](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/90), long before *WebComponents v1* achieved mainstream browser adoption in late 2018. Later, in 2019, [the idea of multiple `ShadowRoots` was revisited](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/780) but found little support from browser vendors.

Comment: So, unless I've missed something, in 2021 a `CustomElement` can only have _one_ `ShadowRoot`. You can optionally give this `ShadowRoot` a reference name and, if you do, that reference name can be whatever you want it to be. **But** it doesn't really matter what name you give it, since whatever you choose will only ever be an _alias_ for `this.shadowRoot`. So you might as well use `this.shadowRoot`.

Answer (score 3):

So a good reason to have a local variable is when one checks for a declarative shadow root.

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    let internals = this.attachInternals();
    let shadow = internals.shadowRoot;

    //No declarative shadow root define, so attach
    if (!shadow) shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

    shadow.addEventListener('slotchange', this.handleSlotChanged);
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    //Load template & content into shadowroot
  }

  handleSlotChanged(e) {
    //handle changes when slot changes
  }
}

customElements.define('my-element', MyElement);
```

```html
<my-element>
  <template>
    <p>Nothing happens - no code to generate template</p>
  </template>
</my-element>
<my-element>
  <template shadowRoot="open">
    <p>Automatically generated due to declarative shadow root</p>
   </template>
</my-element>
```

The local "shadow" variable is assigned with "internals.shadowRoot", but that will be null if the template has no declarative shadow root, so assign it the normal way.

Finally, for both scenarios do something with the "shadow" no matter where it came from, e.g. attach some event handlers...

So one can use the this.shadowRoot in the final bit, but if this.shadowRoot is a property, it carries a little extra overhead. Also, is it really the same as "internals.shadowRoot"?

Answer (score 1):

This is a great example where early code/blogs set the wrong example,
which every Web Component newbie then blindly copy/pastes.

Even the MDN documentation is wrong where it states: *Use super() first*

This is a perfectly valid constructor:

```js
constructor() {
    let myP = document.createElement("p");
    let myText = document.createTextNode("my text");
    myP.append(myText);
    // MDN docs are wrong, you can put code *before* super, 
    // you just can't reference 'this' *before* it is created
    super() // create and return 'this'
        .attachShadow({ mode: "open" }) // create and return this.shadowRoot
        .append(myP);
  }
```

Comment: That's helpful, Danny, thanks. +1 It doesn't really answer my question about declaring an additional arbitrary reference to `this.shadowRoot` though. ;-)

Comment: What is the point of doing ``let d = document`` ?

Comment: I don't know. If we can already reference `document.body` or `document.querySelector()`, what would be the point of declaring `const d = document;` and then referencing `d.body` or `d.querySelector()` ? This is why I'm wondering if I may be missing something important.

Comment: Is there a difference between document and shadowroot?

Comment: One valid reason to use your own/extra reference is to slow down code execution.... but that is about the only 'important' application I can think of  :-)

Comment: Re: _"Is there a difference..."_ Hmmm. Yes, there _are_ differences (albeit ones which might only be acknowledged in _Pedant's Corner_) but... I take your point that in the context of a `WebComponent` then the `shadowRoot` property is pretty much the effective equivalent of `document` in the same way that in a `Service Worker`, the reference `self` is the effective equivalent of `window`.

Comment: Re: _"One valid reason..."_ Right. Good. I think we both share the same perspective on this, then.

Comment: Thanks Danny, just a note on it being a valid constructor, but not necessarily a good idea... the constructor should do as little as possible and not modify the component's html, that should be left for "connectedCallback". Also, the shadowRoot could already have been attached, see https://web.dev/declarative-shadow-dom/, so one needs to check for that.

Comment: Note that Declarative ShadowDOM (after a year) is still a Chromium only party for now [oct 2021], no support yet in FireFox and Safari. And old components that do not check for a shadowRoot do **not** break.

Comment: I do like this approach, but FYI Typescript won't allow it. It requires super() to be its own call, unchained.